# Crystal Report. Using 1 query to generate 3 sub report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have created a report and i want to add 3 subreports in it. The query i want to use for the subreport has a column named  TYPE and it can take the values 1,2 or 3. Right now i have created 3 diffent subreports with different WHERE one for each TYPE. The problem is that the query is too expensive when running alone and it have to run 3 times for each TYPE. Is there a way to run the query 1 time for all TYPES and filter the dataset inside each subreport without asking the database again;
Eg.

TYPE     |      VAL                 Sub1                Sub2                Sub3
1                    5.29             1      5.29          2       6.10        3        8.10
2                    6.10      -->                             2       7.50
2                    7.50
3                    8.10

Comment: My example didn't appear as it should be so don't mind it.

Comment: You may try to find a solution using subreport links. Another option would be to avoid the subreports and create groups (Group by type). Create 3 group sections. When type=1, show the section 1 and hide the others. Do the same for 2 and 3.